# Referencing Table elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

Say for example I have a table layout like this

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="AEimage1">
                row 1 cell 1
            </td>
            <td id="AEimage2">
                row 1 cell 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="setup1">
                row 2 cell 1
            </td>
            <td>
                row 2 cell 2
            </td>
            <td>
                row 2 cell 3
            </td>
            <td>
                row 2 cell 4
            </td>    
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How would I call to an individual row and cell in CSS? So say I wanted to call to [Row2, cell 1], how would I do this? I've tried stacking the elements in CSS like the following:

```
#LinkCSS table tr tr td {
```

But this has not worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

(As a note I realize I can give the cells ID's, and call to them this way. But this is not working for me).

Comment: Is `LinkCSS` your table ID?

Comment: It's a placeholder, but yes it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child` selector and the `:first-child` selector like this:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  color:red;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Br5xd/)

Comment: Would this then make it possible to re-size individual cells?

Comment: @CameoCream yes, you can try adding style `width: 200px` instead of `color:red`, however all the cells in the same column can't have different width unless you use some kind of inline colspan somewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems to be roughly doing what I need. It just needs some tweaking. Cheers.